# How Carburetor/FI will handle fuel supply in high inclination angle

Tags: carburetor, fuel-injectors, fuel-pump

Lets consider, we are going in inclination. (ex:some where > x Degrees).

At this time, how carburetor will pump the fuel into the cylinder. Since of high inclination, it is very difficult for the fuel to climb into the cylinder right? Whatever it is trying to pump, will fall back into the sub (small reservoir) tank right?

I believe the same case for FI too.

Lets assume it is safe altitude and no problem for the air intake too.

May I know, how the system will take care of this situation.

Thanks.

Comment: High inclination angles aren't a problem in general, but in WW2 the British found out the carburettors on their Spitfires didn't work well when the aircraft was upside down or in a steep dive (with negative G-forces), IIRC because the fuel ended up above the float.

Answer (score 2):

For a carburetor, the venturi effect "pulls" the fuel into the air stream, and on a bike the reservoir is directly above the engine (if you can get the reservoir below the engine and still have control that I would like to see...). For a car, the pump pushes fuel into the float chamber and the float controls the level - this works fine landrovers toyotas etc manage very steep angles.

For fuel injection, the pump at the rear or the suction provided by a forward mounted pump is sufficient to supply fuel as long as there is sufficient in the tank to not expose the delivery pipe (valid on all systems).